# change array into a certain sequence

Tags: python, arrays, sequence

How do I calculate the number of operations it would require to change an array into a sequence 'S' of length 'N' where S[i]=S[i+2] for all 'i' in between 1 and 'N'-2 (inclusive)?

For example. A is an array [3,1,3,2].
The answer should be 1.
By replacing the 4th element with 1, we can make A into our required sequence, which would be [3,1,3,1].

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a `counter` with a `for` loop. Cycle through `A` and add 1 to the `counter` if an operation is required

Comment: Do you mean the _minimum_ number of operations? You could start by finding the mode of the odd / even indexed elements to find the number of elements you _don't_ need to change.

Comment: thank you! but how to do the sequence forming part

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you. [I'd be happy to advise further once you've shown a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: Hint: [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is your friend.

Comment: You could also use `statistics.mode`.